Apply a custom function to any number of columns using dplyr
I'm following this example in the dplyr site to program a function that aplies to any number of user supplied columns.
Here is a reprex:
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

trim_whitespace <- function(.data, ...) {
  .data |> mutate(across(..., \(x) str_remove_all(x, "\\s")))
}

# Add whitespace at the end of chr columns
penguins_with_whitespace <- 
  penguins |>
  mutate(across(c(species, island), \(x) paste0(x, " ")))

penguins_with_whitespace |> trim_whitespace(species, island)

This causes the error: 'island' not found. Why is this function not working and what would be the way to fix it?

Basically across thinks you are feeding it island as an object rather than a column in the penguins dataset. The way around it is just to add c(...) or {{}} to the function like this
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

## what the function thinks it is doing 
penguins |>
  mutate(across(species,island, \(x) str_remove_all(x, '\\s')))
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `across(species, island, function(x) str_remove_all(x,
#>   "\\s"))`.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! object 'island' not found


f1 <- function(.data, ... ) {
  .data |> mutate(across(c(...), \(x) str_remove_all(x, "\\s")))
}


f2  <- function(.data, cols ) {
  .data |> mutate(across({{cols}}, \(x) str_remove_all(x, "\\s")))
}



penguins |>
  f1(species, island) |>
  head(1)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 8
#>   species island    bill_length_mm bill_depth_mm flipper_length_mm body_mass_g
#>   <chr>   <chr>              <dbl>         <dbl>             <int>       <int>
#> 1 Adelie  Torgersen           39.1          18.7               181        3750
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: sex <fct>, year <int>

penguins |>
  f2(c(species, island)) |>
  head(1)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 8
#>   species island    bill_length_mm bill_depth_mm flipper_length_mm body_mass_g
#>   <chr>   <chr>              <dbl>         <dbl>             <int>       <int>
#> 1 Adelie  Torgersen           39.1          18.7               181        3750
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: sex <fct>, year <int>

Created on 2024-12-02 with reprex v2.1.1

f1 worked smoothly, thanks a lot! In the other hand, f2 is not in the spirit of the function, but works as well

shouldn't vars(...) work in f1 as a replacement of c(...)?

The superseded versions of vars eg. all_of(...) or  any_of(...)  take quoted variables so theoretically you could change the function to take c('island', 'species' ) but I am not sure that is what you want.

not what I want, I'd rather have the user supply variables by its unquoted name
